# Implementing search functionality in a tree structure with many different types of nodes

Tags: java

I have a tree structure that consists of dozens of types of nodes (each type of node inherits from a `NodeBase` class).

I would like to perform searches on the tree to return a reference to a specific node. For example, suppose there is some `Company` tree, which contains `Department` nodes amongst other types of nodes. `Department` nodes consist of `Employee` nodes. It is assumed that an employee must be part of a department, and can be in exactly one department.

Currently, it is designed so that each node has a list of child nodes of type `NodeBase`. A tree can become quite large, with hundreds of thousands of nodes at times. Insertion/deletion operations are seldom used, while search operations should not take "too long" for these big trees.

Suppose I want to get a reference to an employee node whose `employee ID` field equals some string that I provide. I don't know which department the employee is in, so I'd have to perform a search through all of the nodes hoping to find a match. Not all nodes have an `employee ID` field; departments, for example, do not have them.

I am not sure what is the best way to implement the search functionality, given this tree structure design.

There are probably better ways to design how the data is stored in the first place (eg: using a database?) but currently I am stuck with a tree.

Comment: The first question is: how important is the search functionality in relation to insertion/deletion? Are you going to do a lot of searches and few modifications? If that is the case AND you need the results faster, you can encapsulate several trees ordering by each of the criteria.

Comment: And remember that premature optimization is the root of 90,15% of all evil. Complicate it only you need to.

Comment: Some of the trees can have hundreds of thousands of nodes so it would be useful to implement ways to search quickly. Insertion/deletion will be seldom used. One thing to note is that the nodes are fairly restrictive (eg: only a `Company` node would ever have `Department` child nodes), so if I ever need to search for a department, I don't need to search beyond the departments themselves. Maybe this will help decide what kind of implementation would be good.

Comment: I think the Company example is misleading: it's still the very same problem you have with Employee, just that you need to search fewer parents because of the constraint. If your program only needs to search for companies, then it can be helpful; otherwise I think that having separate registers for different kind of nodes is the best way to have good searching performance, especially since updates to the main tree are infrequent

Comment: The main tree is used for export and validation purposes and is written by predecessors which I do not wish to change because I don't understand it completely, but I can extend the tree-building code if necessary to add extra fields for optimizing search performance while leaving the main tree intact. Can you describe what you mean by encapsulating several trees?

Comment: I think it means you keep N separate sorted indices for the N types of nodes; you must modify the tree code to update the indices when nodes/subtrees are added/removed to the tree. The searches are performed on the sorted indices - this is also what I wrote in my answer

Comment: @Keikoku If the task is to find information in any possible way as opposed to implementing a search from scratch, then use some relational database (most likely the data should be persisted anyway) and simply execute the relevant queries -- let the database engine to the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your tree is **DAG** (directed acyclic tree), use DFS or BFS, for example. Here's a simple BFS:

```
public NodeBase findEmployee (NodeBase root, Integer employeeId) {
    Queue<NodeBase> q= new LinkedList<NodeBase>();
    q.add(root);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        NodeBase node= q.poll();
        if (node instanceof Employee) {
            if (((Employee)node).getId().equals(employeeId))
                return node;
        }
        for (NodeBase child : node.getChildren())
            q.add(child);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Visitor pattern**

Or as [Brabster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096183/1256583) suggested, you can use a visitor pattern. A `NodeBase` should implement an `accept(IVisitor visitor)` method:

```
public class NodeBase {
    //your code
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this); 
        for (NodeBase node : getChildren()) {
            node.accept(visitor);
        }
    }
}
```

IVisitor is just an intercace:

```
public interface IVisitor {
     public void visit(NodeBase node);
}
```

And you need a proper implementation that will do the search:

```
public class SearchVisitor implements IVisitor {

     private Integer searchId;

     public SearchVisitor(Integer searchId) {
          this.searchId= searchId;
     }

     @Override
     public void visit(NodeBase node) {
         if (node instanceof Employee) {
             if (((Employee)node).getId().equals(searchId)) {
                  System.out.println("Found the node " + node.toString() + "!");
             }
         }
     }
}
```

And now, you just simply call it:

```
NodeBase root= getRoot();
root.accept(new SearchVisitor(getSearchId()));
```

Comment: Possible improvement: use something like `NodeBase.find(NodeFinder callback, Class<T> type)` that would allow each node to call themselves with `callback`, and if that returns false, to call `NodeBase.find` with the callback on each of their child nodes that have the correct type. Rather than returning `null` if no object is found, it might be better to have some sort of singleton `NotAMatch` instance of `NodeBase` to avoid NullPointerExceptions, but I haven't implemented something like this before so I'm not really sure if it would be necessary.

Comment: Also, perhaps you could take advantage of multicore processors by having each call to `find()` start a new thread and have a pool for results and just take the first correct result that you get. Or would that produce too much overhead?

Comment: Overhead should not be an issue unless the magnitude of overhead you're thinking of is not the same as what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Data structures are the way you organize your data, and the way you organize data depends on how you actually *use* those pieces of information.

A tree is the right data structure to answer questions like "*get all descendents of node X*", but doesn't help you to solve the problem of "*find me the object with the property X set to Y*" (at least not *your* tree: you could certainly use a tree internally to keep a sorted index as I explain later).

So I think the best way to solve this is using two separate data structures to organize the data: a tree made of `NodeBase` objects to reflect the hierarchical relationship among `NodeBase's`, and a sorted *index* to make the searches with a decent performance. This will introduce a synchronization problem, though, because you'll have to keep the two data structures in sync when nodes are added/removed. If it doesn't happen too frequently, or simply the search performance is critical, then this may be the right way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two parts to this question -- decomposition of class hierarchies and the implementation of the search algorithm.

In the Java world there are two possible solutions to **the problem of decomposition**:

- Object oriented decomposition, which has a local nature, and
- Type checking decomposition using `instanceof` and `type casting`.

Functional languages (including Scala) offer pattern matching, which is really a better approach to implement the type checking decomposition.

Due to the fact that there is a need to work with a data structure (tree) where elements (nodes) can be of varying types, the nature of the decomposition is definitely not local. Thus, the second approach is really the only option.

**The search** itself can be implemented using, for example, binary search tree algorithm. Such tree would need to be constructed out of your data, where the decision where to place a certain node should depend on the actual search criterion. Basically, this means you'd need to have as many trees as there are different search criteria, which is in essence a way to build indexes. The database engines use more sophisticated structures than the binary search tree. For example, [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), but the idea is very similar.

BTW the binary search tree would have a homogeneous nature. For example, if the search pertains to `Employee` by `Department`, then the search tree would consist only of nodes associated with `Employee` instances. This removes the decomposition problem.